# Is it possible to prove $\vdash((\alpha\to \beta)\to \alpha)$?

Tags: logic

Using the following axioms:

A1. (α → (β → α))

A2. (α → (β → γ)) → ((α → β) → (α → γ))

A3. ((¬β → ¬α) → ((¬β → α) → β))

I tried to prove it using the deduction theorem. But the thing is that I can't find a way to get $\alpha$ alone. And also, the formula to prove only has a form like the axiom 3, but we are not working with negations. If it can't be proven, how can I prove that it cannot be proved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is impossible to prove. However, the best way to show this is to exhibit a countermodel, which you might have not learned yet. Intuitively, if $\alpha$ is false, then $\alpha \to \beta$ is true, so the statement $(\alpha \to \beta) \to \alpha$ is false, since truth cannot imply falsity.

Comment: @dedffsd To put it another way: the truth assignment $\alpha=$False immediately prevents the given proposition from being a tautology.

Comment: It’s worth noting that truth assignment also is compatible with all $3$ axioms.